# Rails cannot connect to mysql server windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, localhost, mysql2

I'm trying desperately to connect my new project / any project at all to the mysql2 server. I'm not really sure whether I've correctly installed MySQL server 5.7.21 or not but perhaps someone could advise.
I'm running ruby 2.3, rails 5.0.7 and mysql2 0.5.1. I definitely have mysql2 in my gemfile. I am running this on my 64-bit laptop with Windows 10
Every time I run a `rails db:schema:dump` from my project file in the command prompt, it shows this error:

```
C:\Users\MR_ra\Documents\Sites\matt_radin_cms>rails db:schema:dump --trace
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:schema:dump
rails aborted!
Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' 

(10061)

C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.1-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in `connect'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.1-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:25:in `new'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:25:in `mysql2_connection'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:729:in `new_connection'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:773:in `checkout_new_connection'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:752:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:713:in `acquire_connection'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:490:in `checkout'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:364:in `connection'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:883:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:128:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:91:in `connection'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:241:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:240:in `open'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:240:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `each'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `execute'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:213:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:182:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:14:in `block in run_rake_task'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:11:in `run_rake_task'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `run_command!'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:dump
```

Currently my databases.yml file is looking like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: ***********
  password: ***********
```

My question is also to answer what does the localhost 10061 refer to?

Answer (score 0):

If your `databases.yml` file only like this which is you shared your question then you update little bit like this

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: xxxxxxxxxxx
  password: xxxxxxxxxxx
  #=> if live server
  #=> socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock 

#=> for developmen
development:
  <<: *default
  database: project_development

 #=> for test
test:
  <<: *default
  database: project_test

#=> for production
production:
  <<: *default
  database: project_production
  username: xxxxxxxxxx
  password: xxxxxxxxxx
```

then `rails db:create`

Actually, that is my configuration which already working

***Note:*** If you developing locally and not set any password for `mysql` then `username` and `password` will look like this

```
username: root
password:
```

> If you use [`WAMP`](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [`XAMPP`](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) you must run this before running rails command. The [`WAMP`](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) is recommended for windows.

that means by default `username` is `root` and `password` is empty.

You can by default set up this configuration if you will run this command for creating a **Rails** project

```
rails new project_name -d mysql
```